# Zend Framework 3 Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, controller, zend-framework3

Background: I am using REST methods only.
I've called a `create()` method, which returns the id of the record I have created, and I want to call a different controller's `get()` method with that id.

module.config.php :

```
namespace PrivateStatement;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Method;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'privateStatement' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/private-statements/private-statements',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\PrivateStatementController::class,
                    ],
                ],
                'child_routes' => [
                    'get' => [
                        'type' => Method::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'verb' => 'get',
                            'defaults' => [
                                'modules' => [

                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                    ],
                    'post' => [
                        'type' => Method::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'verb' => 'post',
                            'defaults' => [
                                'modules' => [

                                ],
                                'params' => [

                                ],
                                'requestVo' => '',
                                'controller' => Controller\PrivateStatementCreateController::class,
                            ],
                        ],
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'strategies' => [
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ],
    ],
];
```

In the PrivateStatementCreateController, I have the `create()` function:

```
public function create($data)
{
    $requiredParams = [
        PrivateStatementConstants::COLUMN_PROPERTY_ID,
        PrivateStatementConstants::COLUMN_STOCK_UNIT_ID,
        PrivateStatementConstants::API_FROM,
        PrivateStatementConstants::API_TO,
    ];
    $validRequest = ControllerUtil::verifyRequiredParams($requiredParams, $data);
    if ($validRequest) {
        $personId = $this->authResult->getIdentity();
        $id = $this->model->createPrivateStatementService(
            $data[PrivateStatementConstants::COLUMN_PROPERTY_ID],
            $data[PrivateStatementConstants::COLUMN_STOCK_UNIT_ID],
            $data[PrivateStatementConstants::API_FROM],
            $data[PrivateStatementConstants::API_TO],
            $personId
        );
        if ($id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('privateStatement', array('action' => 'get', 'params' => array('private_statement_id' => $id)));
        } else {
            $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_400);
        }
    } else {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_400);
    }

    return new JsonModel([]);
}
```

The part I'm currently struggling with is `return $this->redirect()->toRoute('privateStatement', array('action' => 'get', 'params' => array('private_statement_id' => $id)));`

When I call this an exception gets thrown with the message `Part route may not terminate` - I honestly don't know how to continue from here - I only need to  call the `get()` function in the PrivateStatementController and return the results.

Comment: Does it work if you change the first argument of the redirect call from `privateStatement` to `privateStatement/get`?

Comment: @TimFountain unfortunately not :(